# Allocating array of structures in function

Tags: c, pointers, allocation

I want to dynamically allocate an array of structures in a function, then fill it (in the same function) and print it in main.

```
typedef struct{
    int x;
}str;

void fc(str **data, int length){
    *data = malloc(length*sizeof(str));
    for(int i=0; i<length;i++){
        scanf("%d", &data[i]->x);
    }
}

int main(){
    str *data;
    int length=5;
    fc(&data, length);
    for(int i=0; i<length;i++){
        printf("%d", data[i].x);
    }
}
```

`Scanf()` works for `data[0]`, but for `data[>=1]` it stops working, so I suppose something there is something wrong with my usage of `malloc`.

Comment: `&data[i]->x` should be `&(*data)[i]->x`

Comment: Equivalently, you could also use `&data[0][i]->x` instead of `&(*data)[i]->x` if you think that looks nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
scanf("%d", &data[i]->x);
```

should be:

```
scanf("%d", &(*data)[i].x);
```

You need to dereference `data` to get a pointer to the first element, then index into that array and take the address of the field. It would be simpler if you had kept `*data` as a separate variable inside the function.

The allocation looks correct. You should also add code to check that `scanf()` really succeeded before relying on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not because of `malloc`, but its is because of `&data[i]->x`.

This needs to be changed to `&(*data)[i]->x`. You must access the `value at (or more sophisticated: dereference)` data.

Also, some improvements required:

- Check if `malloc` returned NULL, handle the error if thats the case
- Check return value of `scanf`